# vue-cli-service build --target lib does not respect @ paths

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

**Edit:**

I've managed to get the javascript part `vue-cli-service build --target lib` to respect the `@` paths by cd'ing into the project's root directory before running the command. The SASS compilation still does not work.

---

I'm building a bunch of vue components into a library I intend to use in a legacy app. To that end I've plugged the components I want in the library into their own `buildList.js` and global application styles into `styles.scss`. I also wrote a script `build.sh` that copies the resulting files to the legacy app's directory. This script is called through a package.json reference `yarn buildLib`

The problem is that when building the project using `yarn buildLib`, `vue-cli-service build` does not resolve the `@` in import paths and fails to find my files. If I use relative paths to point at the collections (buildList.js, styles.scss) the imports within their imports will fail.

The default vue-cli webpack scripts `yarn serve` and `yarn build` interpret the `@` correctly.

I am not altering the default webpack configuration in any way so I'm expecting `@` to resolve to the `src/` directory in any use case.

Why is this not working?

---

Build Output:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 21 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     10:08:17

These dependencies were not found:

* @/components/controls/ColorPicker in ./collections/buildList.js
* @/components/controls/DateTimeInput in ./collections/buildList.js
* @/components/controls/FilterInput in ./collections/buildList.js
* etc

Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  @import '~@/assets/styles/reset';
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  collections/styles.scss 7:11  root stylesheet
```

---

build.sh

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

# Consistent working dir please
cd "${0%/*}"

legacyPath="${HOME}/Documents/etc"

vue-cli-service build --target lib --name app 'collections/buildList.js'
sass collections/styles.scss dist/app-styles.css

cp dist/app.umd.js ${legacyPath}/app.js
cp dist/app-styles.css ${legacyPath}/app-styles.css
```

---

buildList.js

```
import Vue           from 'vue';
import ColorPicker   from '@/components/controls/ColorPicker';
import DateTimeInput from '@/components/controls/DateTimeInput';
import FilterInput   from '@/components/controls/FilterInput';
[...]
```

---

styles.scss

```
  @import '~@/assets/styles/reset';
  @import '~@/assets/styles/general';
  [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was all me. The ~@ and @ shortcuts are provided by webpack which is wrapped by vue-cli-service. Thus, to build both the sass and js we need to invoke it thusly from the project root:

`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name app 'src/buildList.js' 'src/styles.scss'`